# Getting error while testing with Jest: Vue and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuelayers

getting this error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/david/Workspace/dts-sdk-example-solution/solution/frontend/src/main/frontend/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { default } from "../defineProperty/_index.mjs"
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

while trying to execute the test.

This is my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...require("@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel/jest-preset"),
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(vuelayers|ol))'],
}
```

Trying to use vuelayers which does not supply any typings..